# Android: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash

We see the following crash happens quite frequntly, only on android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4
The stack trace does not include any frame of our code, its only android, so we're having trouble understanding what causes it or how to work around it.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:118)
       at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:393)
       at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:892)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11053)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11056)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10490)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
       at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10455)
       at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:851)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1932)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1656)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2470)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4499)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Hello Guy! Did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm facing it too. Thanks, Simha.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183896
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184001

If you are using animations during fragment transitions try to disable it.